# CSS background image not showing?

Tags: html, css

The background image is not appearing for the body section in CSS. I've tried various things such as background: rather than background-image in css and I've tried url("path") and url(path) and url(../path) and url("(../path) and still nothing O.O Help!

Update: 
I found various solutions. I believe creating a folder within my css folder called images made it easier to find. Also, not using \ and using / instead. Using an online host. Thank you all. I am very satisfied.

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hoola</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Abdi\Desktop\CSS\Navigationfromleftstyle.css"/>
</head>
<body >
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Navigationfromleftstyle.css:

```
html{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}

body {

    max-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    background:url("C:\Users\Abdi\Desktop\cartographer\cartographer\cartographerbig.png");
    padding:0;

}

.nav {

    width:100px;

}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use full path to your image, you should set a relative url to your website such as localhost:80/images/myBackground.png

Comment: it works if i do it in html e.g. <img src="full file path" />. How would i get it to local host?

Comment: Where is your 'html' full path? Is that 'C:\Users\Abdi\Desktop\cartographer\cartographer'?

Answer (score 1):

You can host your image on your web server.
But there is another nice solution, you can go to this [site](https://www.base64-image.de/) and load your image and then get css code for that image and this should load your image as you wish.
it's called base64 encoding.

And if you want to run it from a local folder without an local server you should use the file:/// keyword like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/Abdi/Desktop/cartographer/cartographer/cartographerbig.png
```

and note that you should use / instead of \

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked but seems cumbersome and less sustainable in the long term sense and i'd like to see other solutions before finalizing this.

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye this is robust the string you get it's permanent because all the data is inside of this string, it's not like a file share or something. how do you run your website on your local machine?

Comment: it's on my local machine. I don't run the website. I'm just learning to create one .

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye because you don't use a local server i updated my answer with the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the required image in your project directory and make the following changes.

```
body {

    max-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url("images\cartographerbig.png");
    padding:0;

}
```

**Edited:**

Lets say the page your executing is index.html.

If your have not created any directory then create one directory/folder called my_website(name it as per your requirement) and paste the index.html file inside my_website folder.

Now create another folder inside my_website folder called images and place your image file inside images

your directory structure should like this

```
my_website/index.html
my_website/images/cartographerbig.png
```

Comment: How do I do that? What does project directory mean? I'm a noob learning to create websites

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relative path. like: 'http://www.google.com/images/1.png'

just create one directory images beside your css folder and put your images inside that folder and you can give body path like

```
body {
max-height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
background:url("../../images/Chrysanthemum.jpg");
padding:0;
```

}

this will help

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
body {
     background:url("img/01.png"); /*  location: root  */
     background:url("../../img/01.png"); /* location: outside your current folder */
     background:url("/website/projectname/gallery/img/01.png");   /* your localhost */
     background:url("http://www.thephotoargus.com/img/01.jpg");   /* external site */
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the url `background:url("C:\\Users\\Abdi\\Desktop\\cartographer\\cartographer\\cartographerbig.png");`
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input 
The "\" should not be used instead use "/"

Comment: \ is an escape sequence  hence \\ needs to be used